# Правильное управление во фразе

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, управление, лексическая-сочетаемость

Друзья!
Объясните, пожалуйста, верное ли управление во фразе ниже:

**"Депутат предложил дать отсрочку жителям города на платежи по аренде жилья".**

Или вместо *"...отсрочки на платежи по аренде жилья"* правильнее сказать: *"...предложил дать отсрочку по арендной плате для жителей города".*

Вообще аренда и плата - очень коварные вещи.

Что предполагает норма? Помогите разобраться. :)

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Депутат предложил дать отсрочку жителям города на платежи по аренде жилья.
```

Мне эта фраза вообще видится корявой.Лучше построить предложение по схеме: дать кому? что? какую отсрочку? каких платежей?:

*Депутат предложил дать жителям города (что?)  отсрочку (чего?) платежей (каких?) по аренде (какой? чего?) жилья.*

*Платежи **по аренде*** - использовано второе значение слова аренда - **плата** за наём, а не сам наём. (Как **платежи по кредитному договору**, платежи по рассрочке) Возможно и первое значение: *Депутат предложил дать жителям города   отсрочку платежей за аренду  жилья*.

Или: *Депутат предложил дать жителям города  отсрочку арендной платы за жильё.*

Или: *Депутат предложил дать жителям города   отсрочку арендных платежей за жильё*.

По поводу управления слова *отсрочка* посмотрим словарь Розенталя "Управление в русском языке:

> Отсрочка **Ч е г о** и **в ч е м**. Отсрочка сдачи экзаменов. Отсрочка
>   исполнения приговора. Получить отсрочку в призыве на военную службу.

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/rection_rosenthal/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0

Как видим, отсрочка на что-то - ненормативное управление, разговорное.